# Sybase ASE triggers exception 11040 when joining a subquery

Tags: sql, join, subquery, sap-ase

To avoid bad performance when using OR as a Join condition I tried to create a subquery.

The basic-idea was something like this:

```
select * from maintable 
LEFT JOIN table1 ON maintable.id = table1.id
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id_vor = table2.id
-- here it becomes tricky 
LEFT JOIN maintableTOtable3 ON (maintable.id = maintableTOtable3.id_vor) or (maintable.id = maintableTOtable3.id)
LEFT JOIN table3 on maintableTOtable3.id = table3.id or maintableTOtable3.id_vor = table3.id
```

I know that this will perform very bad... Thats why I [found](http://www.sqlnuggets.com/blog/performance-problem-when-using-or-in-a-join/) and try this:

```
left join ( 
    select id_vor as "id", id as "id_vor"
    from maintableTOtable3
    union 
    select id as "id", id_vor as "id_vor"
    from maintableTOtable3
) subquery on subquery.id = maintable.id 
left join table3 on subquery.id_vor = table3.id
```

When I try to run this I got the following error from Sybase:

> SQL-Fehler [11040] [ZZZZZ]: Adaptive Server cannot perform the
> requested action because column 'id' is not within the scope of the
> joined table expression. Check your command for missing or incorrect
> database objects, variable names, and/or input data.

So the column 'id' is the column of my subquery. I know the because I named the column in the original-code different.

Can somebody explain me why this error drops? What is wrong?

I am using Adaptive Server Enterprise/12.5.4

Comment: I don't have access to `ASE 12.5.4` instance so can't rule out an issue with that version but in `ASE 15.7` I wrote a small test query that (I think) mimics your query and I get no errors; since you've only provided a portion of the problematic query it's not possible (for me) to tell if the issue is with the snippet you've provided or some other part of your query; I'd suggest updating your question with a minimal query that demonstrates the issue, and since we don't have access to your DDL I'd recommend a query that references system tables (which everyone has access to)

Comment: google search on `sybase join union "not within the scope of the joined table expression"` brings up a few hits that indicate an issue/bug with ASE when using an ANSI join with a derived table that includes a `union` - see [this](https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/hibernate-issues/2009-January/013482.html) and [this](https://blog.csdn.net/damenggege123/article/details/12619107); if this **is** an issue with `ASE 12.5.4` perhaps those links will give you idea on a fix